# In ruby, how create UTC time for an arbitrary future time in an arbitrary timezone, accounting for DST (when applicable)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

In a scheduling method, I need to take a (local_date, local_time, and local_time_zone), and return the corresponding utc time *accounting* for whether Daylight Saving time is in effect on *that* date.

I do not want to change Time.zone since while threadsafe, it has the entirely unexpected result of persisting across multiple requests - a Bad Thing.

The following (0800 Pacific time) does NOT work because they return the same time in UTC (16:00) even though the first day (Oct 1) IS in daylight saving time and the second day (Dec 1) is NOT in daylight savings time, so the UTC should be different

```
Time.new(2012, 10, 1, 8, 0, 0, ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Pacific Time (US & Canada)'].utc_offset).utc
# 2012-10-01 16:00:00 UTC <<<< should be 15:00

Time.new(2012, 12, 1, 8, 0, 0, ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Pacific Time (US & Canada)'].utc_offset).utc
# 2012-12-01 16:00:00 UTC
```

I had hoped that the .utc method would take into account whether the daylight saving is in effect, but it doesn't.

I'm not sure if I should be using a Time object, a DateTime object, and TimeWith Zone, etc.

===

Note: There IS a way to do it using the Chronic gem (below). But I would like to use the built-in Ruby Date and Time methods to get the same (eg, correct) result:

```
Chronic.time_class =ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]
Chronic.parse("10/1/2012 0800").utc
# 2012-10-01 15:00:00 UTC 
Chronic.parse("12/1/2012 0800").utc
# 2012-12-01 16:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on another SO thread: the trick is to put the time (and zone) into a format usable by Time.parse:

```
Time.parse("2012-10-1 8:00:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)").utc
# 2012-10-01 15:00:00 UTC 

Time.parse("2012-12-1 8:00:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)").utc
# 2012-12-01 16:00:00 UTC
```

ANOTHER METHOD (probably better):

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"].parse("2012-12-1 8am").utc
```

After some playing around it looks like we were right to be wary of changing Time.zone simply to create a time in a certain zone -- setting Time.zone can 'stick' over multiple requests (in the same thread). So if you have two different windows open to a rails app, and are viewing two different accounts, setting Time.zone for the account in one window can actually change the Time.zone in the other window for the other account.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through something similar and found Time.zone.local to work fine taking daylight savings into account.  I'm not sure about US daylight savings, but here in Australia daylight savings kick in on the 6th October 2013.

The following code seems to work fine for me:

```
1.9.3-p194 :009 > Time.zone = 'Sydney'
 => "Sydney" 
1.9.3-p194 :010 > Time.zone.local(2013, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0).utc
 => 2013-09-30 14:00:00 UTC 
1.9.3-p194 :011 > Time.zone.local(2013, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0).utc
 => 2013-10-09 13:00:00 UTC
```

Are you sure your dates / time zones are correct?  Seems that Pacific Time experiences daylight savings in November according to this page:
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=137

Comment: I worry about using Time.zone = xxx since it's unclear (to me) what the 'scope' is... I don't want to change the system time zone each time I want to calculate the time. As quick example, if I use rails console, and define a new method, and inside the method I set Time.zone = 'Hawaii', then after invoking the method the console Time.zone has been changed, which tells me setting Time.zone might affect the Time.zone in other methods too!

Comment: also, for USA today is the day Daylight savings ended, so October 1 is IN DST and Dec 1 is not DSL.